# Mysql GROUP_CONCAT of first n rows

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to get comma separated value of first n (say 10 rows of a column) rows using Mysql?

I have a query to get data greater than CURDATE(). And it will return more than 100 rows of result. What I want is, GROUP_CONCAT the first 10 rows of result.

This is my query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) AS userids
FROM user_tasks
WHERE due_date > CURDATE() LIMIT 10;
```

am getting entire rows. I need first 10 rows only

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you having with your current code? Can you post it?

Comment: Just add a `SUBSTRING_INDEX` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index and an `order by` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat to your `group_concat`

Comment: hi Clive, updated with my code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use subquery:

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) AS userids
FROM
  (SELECT 
    user_id
  FROM
    user_tasks
  WHERE due_date > CURDATE()
  LIMIT 10) AS users
```

Comment: Thanks Alma, its works. I was trying with subquery, but then with where condition.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use a sub query to impose the limit, like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sub_query.user_id) AS userids
FROM 
(
  SELECT user_id
  FROM user_tasks
  WHERE due_date > CURDATE() 
  LIMIT 10
) sub_query
```